# Trouble getting webViewDidStartLoad and webViewDidFinishLoad to work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiwebview

The web view loads the page. It doesn't call the `webViewDidStartLoad` or `webViewDidFinishLoad` methods.

**N_NumberAppDelegate.h:**

```
@interface N_NumberAppDelegate : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

@end
```

**N_NumberAppDelegate.m:**

```
@implementation N_NumberAppDelegate

@synthesize window;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 480)];
    [webView  loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/NNum_Results.aspx?NNumbertxt=2N"]]];
    [window addSubview:webView];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [window release];
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"Started loading");
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"Finshed loading");
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

i think you have forgot to set your delegate.
ie `webView.delegate=self;`

good luck